# Recalling a function iteratively

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration, logic

I have a question about recalling my function within a loop.

Below is my code:

```
List_new = myfunction()
for items in List_new:
    if(my condition is TRUE):
        Execute some commands
    if(my condition is FALSE):
        recall myfunction()
```

My problem is that I am loading "List_new" using myfunction(). How can I change "List_new" iteratively when my condition is False. I want to reload the function especially when the condition is FALSE. This means I keep calling the function until it is false and then execute the final output from myfunction().

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is hard to understand, where is myfunction() defined? my condition is not allowed in python since it has spaces, you need to post the full code.

Comment: @rydex the term you're looking for is [mre]

Comment: The question was about the general logical direction. An oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume the list generated by `myfunction()` is a constant size.

You can use a while loop:

```
List_new = myfunction()
index=0
while index < len(List_new):
    
    items = List_new[index]
    if(my condition is TRUE):
        #Execute some commands
        i+=1
    if(my condition is FALSE):
        List_new = myfunction()
```

Keep in mind that this solution will have an infinite loop if `myfunction()` continuously generates false values. If you can guarantee that all values will eventually be `True` then it should always terminate.